# Postgresql streaming replication with restore_command for archived WAL files

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a primary server that archives (and gzips) WAL files into `/wal/archive/`. At the moment, I'm attempting to set up a hot standby with streaming replication from a base backup.

When starting up the standby, I noticed it was producing errors such as:

```
could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000142400000014 has already been removed
```

This makes sense, as it's been around a day since the base_backup was taken, and the WAL files have already been archived. I provided a `restore_command` in the standby server's `recovery.conf` to scp the file over from the primary and unzip it:

```
restore_command = '(set -o pipefail; scp primary_ip:/wal/archive/%f.gz /dev/stdout | pigz -d > "%p")'
```

Strangely, the same errors kept appearing. Keep in mind, I have tested the above command works when I run it and provide a file. I wanted to see if the command was actually being run, so I added an echo:

```
restore_command = '(set -o pipefail; echo "%f" >> /data/test.txt && scp primary_ip:/wal/archive/%f.gz /dev/stdout | pigz -d > "%p")'
```

I can clearly see it is not running the command as /data/test.txt is not being created. The `postgres` user has permission to write to `/data/`. Is there something that needs to be specified on the standby to instruct it to use `restore_command` when the primary has already archived a WAL file?

My recovery.conf file has been set up according to section 25.2.4 of the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html).

Comment: Did you remove the files from `pg_xlog` on your replication server?

Comment: When I restored it from the backup the `pg_xlog` only had one file in it called `archive_status`. I just tried deleting that file and the same errors still occur. It's worth noting I've also tried removing `primary_conninfo` from recovery.conf to see if I can force it to use `restore_command` but it still doesn't call it. The only settings set in recovery.conf are `restore_command`, `standby_mode` and `trigger_file`.

Comment: When I start it up, it says `entering standby mode`, `incomplete startup packet`, then `the database system is starting up` 10-15 times, and then `incomplete startup packet` again.

Comment: You only ned to remove the files from `pg_xlog`, not the folder.

Comment: Correct, I didn't remove the folder. I tried removing the `archive_status` file inside as a last ditch effort when it wasn't working.

Comment: Same, don't remove anything there. Basically, you need to do `rm -f pg_xlog/*`. Anyways, I'd check the config file once again following the manual step by step, check for network connectivity issues and then redoing it again from zero.

Comment: @Alex there's no reason the primary would need `restore_command` set somewhere, correct? In case it could somehow hit the archive and stream it over to the secondary.

Comment: nope, `restore_command` is only needed on the "slave", you only need to edit `postgresql.conf`  on the primary server.